# Counting the number of times a class appears on a page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a solution to counting the number of times a class appears on a page using Javascript.

The solution should not use a library and should be compatible with older browsers.

The only answers I am able to find use jQuery or are only suitable for newer browsers.

Comment: "older" is not formal enough. Is Mosaic old enough?

Comment: ``console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.classname').length)``

Answer (score 3):

You can loop though all the elements and count the elements with a specific class:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    if (el[i].className == 'asdf') cnt++;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R5XUU/

This will work in IE6 and later.

If the page has elements with multiple class names, you would need to check for the class name within the class property:

```
if ((' ' + el[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' asdf ') != -1) cnt++;
```

Comment: But it will not work with multiple classes assigned to the same element. You will have to explode/split the classes and then check.

Comment: @Karl: I just added code for that.

Comment: Wow. Creative use of getElementsByTagName. I've always used recursion for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this :

```
var classCount = document.getElementsByClassName("className").length;
alert(classCount);
```

Comment: Relevant: http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

Should work in IE4, you could use `document.layers` if you need Netscape support.

```
matches = 0;

for(i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++)
{
   if(document.all(i).className.indexOf('votecell') != -1)
   {
       matches++;
   }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ta2q5/)